# navigator.userAgent NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE

Tags: firefox, undefined

I am getting a NS_ERROR_NOT_AVAILABLE error in Firefox on this line of code:

```
var
    rmsie = /(msie) ([\w.]+)/,
    msie = (_noDOM) ? '' : rmsie.exec(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())||[],
```

navigator.userAgent is undefined when I examine it in the debugger.

Google search has been fruitless... Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I have to specify window.navigator.userAgent (if I'm going to sniff userAgent at all), as, apparently, navigator is a different object than window.navigator. How does that work?

EDIT: I just tried again today and it still doesn't work. Is there some use case where userAgent may not be defined, yet? Is there a better way to detect whether I am using the IE browser?

UPDATE: After doing some digging, I discovered there was some extension or plugin to the browser I was using, that was stripping off the user-agent information, leading to any reference to navigator.userAgent throwing an exception. Therefore, this issue can be put to bed.